# How to put a sentence in a every line of List in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The UI structure of app looks like this [image]

```
struct SheetView: View {
var body: some View {
    List{
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 5)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .opacity(50)
        HStack{
            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 100)

            Text("How does diagnostic prediction works?")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(25)

        }
        Text("This app tries to predict medical diagnosys by given symptoms. It curently works with the given symptoms:")


        // not a fancy way
        Text("abdominal pain")
        Text("abnormal menstruation")
        Text("acidity")
        Text("acute liver failure")
        Text("altered sensorium")
        Text("anxiety")

            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .lineSpacing(10)
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding(20)
}
```

}

I have a big list of symptoms ( text ) and I want to put every symptom in a List. I tried to stack it something like

```
Text("abdominal pain")
        Text("abnormal menstruation")
        Text("acidity")
        Text("acute liver failure")
        Text("altered sensorium")
        Text("anxiety")
```

but it's not a fancy way. What is the best practice to put a sentence in every line of List without stacking it using Text()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `String`s in an array using `ForEach` and have it return at `Text` with that element seems like the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach(diagsosysList, id: \.self) { symptom in
   Text(symptom)
}
```

Comment: Please add some context why you think this is a correct solution.